# Why on refresh browser getting Error HTTP Status 412

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, http, tomcat

I am wondering about the behavior of my application. In Chrome browser when I launch for 1st time it works fine. but as soon as refresh the browser i get below error and if i refresh again its works fine. for every alternate refresh the application end up in showing below error page.
I trying few work around to get the reason for the behavior but didn't get anything.
Note: This behavior is specific to Chrome browser, its working fine in other browsers.

Error after page refresh:-

[image]

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Updated:

[image]

Below are extra request params present during the failing scenario(HTTP-412) in network log

```
       {
          "name": "If-None-Match",
          "value": "W/\"12649-1551875089324\""
        },
        {
          "name": "If-Modified-Since",
          "value": "Wed, 06 Mar 2019 12:24:49 GMT"
        }
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual HTTP messages (Developer tools, Network...)

Comment: @Julian attached is the error i m getting

Comment: The *network* log.

Comment: @JulianReschke i tried to look the network logs. and even i compared the working and not working scenario and figured out that in request parameters 2 param are extra in 412 HTTP case. But i am not sure what are these and from where these are added. i have added the param in updated part

Comment: @JulianReschke Let me know if something you figure out with this

Comment: The second request contains two preconditions, and apparently the server is broken in that it incorrectly handles them for a GET request (where a 304, not a 412 would be expected). Seems to be a server bug, assuming this *is* a GET request.

Comment: @JulianReschke i have tried my level best to figure out the root cause. If you can help me out, i will be very thankful. if you need network logs i can share with you.

Comment: If the seconf request is a GET, then you need to debug the server.

Comment: Ok I will try to debug server side as well